# How to auto run vagrant fsnotify?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I am developing angular4 app using vagrant. I have installed [vagrant-fsnotify plugin](https://github.com/adrienkohlbecker/vagrant-fsnotify) in order to notify file system changes to trigger hot build. The problem I have is how to run automatically `vagrant fsnotify` when vagrant booted?

Comment: Did you ever find a workablesolution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [vagrant-trigger](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) can help you run this command everytime you boot your vm. An example should be like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    # Your existing Vagrant configuration
     ...

     # start fsnotify on host after the guest starts
     config.trigger.after :up do
         run "vagrant fsnotify"
     end
end
```

Comment: The plugin `vagrant-trigger` has been merged into Vagrant so there's no need to install explicitly, just use the configuration as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Correct form of trigger statement is:

```
  # start fsnotify on host after the guest starts
  config.trigger.after :up do |trigger|
    trigger.run = {inline: "bash -c 'vagrant fsnotify > output.log 2>&1 &'"}
  end
```